# Common or popular Configuration Management Software

Tags: deployment, automation, configuration-management

What are the most commonly used (or most popular) configuration management software packages available?

Comment: Just scratching the surface (and a few details)... Many of the issues you raise are discussed in principle form in [The Pragmatic Programmer](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer). For example, [every piece of knowledge has a single, unambiguous, authoritative representation within a system](http://pragmatictips.com/11).

I've used WPKG but wonder if chef would be better. For generating config files, look at [T4](https://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/) for text files and [Slow Cheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) for .NET config files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The four most popular configuration management software packages are: **[Chef](https://www.chef.io/products/enterprise-automation-stack)**, **[Puppet](https://www.puppet.com/why-puppet/use-cases/continuous-configuration-automation)**, **[Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/use-cases/configuration-management)** and **[Salt](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/states/index.html)**.  They are reviewed in [this article](http://www.infoworld.com/d/data-center/review-puppet-vs-chef-vs-ansible-vs-salt-231308) and in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T56uN6N_hs0).  Bottom line: Chef and Puppet have been around much longer and thus are more established but some would argue that Salt and Ansible offer more elegant solutions.  A [more exhaustive list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software) of open-source configuration management software in available on Wikipedia.  I chose [Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/index.html) because it's powerful, easy to learn/use, requires no daemons, no agents, no dedicated management host, no PKI, no extra databases, and no clients or open ports because it uses SSH.